# iPhone SDK Tableview Datasource singleton error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, sdk

I basically followed apple "TheElements" sample and changed "PeriodicElements" .h & .m to my own "SortedItems" .h & .m

During compile I get this error:

> "Undefined symbols:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SortedItems",
>   referenced from:
>         __objc_classrefs__DATA@0 in SortedByNameTableDataSource.o ld:
>   symbol(s) not found collect2: ld
>   returned 1 exit status "

How do i figure this out? hehe

Comment: Please don't put things like "HELP! been stuck on this all day" in a question title.

Comment: Please dont post useless (non)helpful answers..

Comment: I wasn't posting an answer. I was posting a comment. Also, I did not change your question. You can see this in the edit history of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/3019946/revisions

Comment: Yes i realized that after i posted, my mistake - jumped to conclusions. Sorry.  I guess i just wanted to point out the comment was useless..

Comment: The comment wasn't useless; it was advice on how to better post a question.

Answer (score 0):

That's a linker error.  Most likely you forgot to add SortedItems.m to your project so it's not compiling and linking the implementation of SortedItems.

The other possibility is that you misspelled SortedItems in your `@implementation` statement.

Comment: well after a bunch of goofing around and restarting my computer i seem to have eliminated that error but now i get this one...



arm-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1:  conflicting code gen style switches are used
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1

any ideas on that one?